# Code does not compare on conditional Statement

Tags: python

The following code works perfectly but when I call function in another file and read data in chunks it gives error mentioned at the end.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep= ";", skiprows=8)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Y = list(df.iloc[:, 2].abs())

def PeakCounts(Y):
    W = np.argmax(Y)
    X = list()
    for i in reversed(range(W+1)):
        if Y[i] > Y[i-1]:
            X.append(i)
        else:
            break
    return(len(X))
```

Script

```
from Amplitude import Amplitude
from PeakCount import PeakCounts
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dat = pd.read_csv('file.csv', skiprows=8, sep=';')
df = pd.DataFrame(dat)
Z = np.array(df.iloc[:, 2].abs())
chunk_size = 100000

for i in range(0, len(Z), chunk_size):
    NewList = []
    NewList.append(Z[i:i+chunk_size])
    print(PeakCounts(NewList))
    print(Amplitude(NewList))
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Master.py", line 21, in <module>
    print(PeakCounts(NewList))
  File "PeakCount.py", line 20, in PeakCounts5
    if Y[i] > Y[i-1]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Aside: if you only need the length of `X`, not its  content, you don't need a list. Just increment a counter.

Comment: The problem is that `Y[i] > Y[i-1]` doesn't make sense if `i=0`, which will happen if `W=0`. I cannot write an answer however because I don't know what you are trying to do...